# CSS Landscape letter print alignment

Tags: css

While trying to print as letter and landscape, so that i can use the entire width of the page,the two divs donot align with each other. However, when i try and print with "@size a4 landscape" the two divs align. 
What am i missing on my print CSS that will make them align just like they do on the screen.

```css
<style>
    @media print {
      .column-left {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
      }
      .column-right {
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
      }
      .column-center {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 40%;
      }
      th.vendorListHeading {
        background-color: #ec6619 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        font-size: small;
        width: inherit;
      }
      th.vendorListHeading1 {
        background-color: #666666 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        font-size: small;
      }
      thead.vendorListHeading2 {
        background-color: #666666 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        font-size: small;
      }
      td.forPrintingonlyfortd {
        color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
        font-size: small;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-style: normal;
      }
      .StandardTable thead tr th {
        background-color: #666666 !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        font-size: small;
      }
      @page {
        size: letter landscape;
      }
      body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .table {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ec6619;
      }
      .table>tbody>tr>td,
      .table>tbody>tr>th,
      .table>tfoot>tr>td,
      .table>tfoot>tr>th,
      .table>thead>tr>td,
      .table>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 3px;
      }
      .table>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 3px;
      }
      .table-condensed>tbody>tr>td,
      .table-condensed>tbody>tr>th,
      .table-condensed>tfoot>tr>td,
      .table-condensed>tfoot>tr>th,
      .table-condensed>thead>tr>td,
      .table-condensed>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 3px;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
      a[href]:after {
        content: none;
      }
      td.forPrintingonlyforTd {
        color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
        font-size: small;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-style: normal;
      }
      .container {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
      }
      .col-md-6 {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
      }
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<HTML>



<HEAD>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

</HEAD>



<body>






  <div class="container">





    <table class="table" border="1">


      <tr>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th width="70%" bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>



      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table" border="1">
      <tr>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>



        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd">
                  Title
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>


        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table class="table" border="1">

            <tr>

              <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </th>
            </tr>



            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>



      </tr>











    </table>



    <div class="container">

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <table class="table" border="1">

          <tr>

            <td>

              <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
              <img src="" alt="" />

            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">





        <table class="table" border="1">

          <tr>

            <th bgcolor="ec6619" class="vendorListHeading" align="left"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
            </th>




            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>


        </table>

        <table class="table" border="1">

          <tr>

            <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
            </th>
          </tr>



          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>


        </table>
        <table class="table" border="1">

          <tr>

            <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF"> Title</font>
            </th>
          </tr>



          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>


        </table>

        <table class="table" border="1">

          <tr>

            <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF"> Title</font>
            </th>
          </tr>



          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>

        <table class="table" border="1">

          <tr>

            <th bgcolor="ec6619" align="left" class="vendorListHeading"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
            </th>
          </tr>



          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="forPrintingonlyforTd"><font color="FFFFFF">Title</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>



      </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but would it help to correct all the errors in your source first?

Comment: Lister, what error are you referring to ?

Comment: The errors in the HTML. [The W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org) reports 8 errors and 5 warnings, and they don't even count all the missing `#`s in color values. When I run it through my own validator, I get 36 errors in HTML mode or 44 errors in XHTML mode.

Answer (score 0):

Lister,

I did correct those errors and was able to figure out the root cause.
The problem was that i was not including the col-md-6 under the class="row". Once the col-md-6 were under div class="row", it was showing properly everywhere.